# When Calculate is set to Manual, calculation still occurs

Tags: microsoft-excel

If you write in some arithmetic formulae interdependencies across several cells, they still update in responsive real time when an independent variable is changed, even if Formulas!Calculation Options is set to Manual.  So what's the point of the Manual feature?

Comment: I thought this had to do primarily with calcing circular references.

Comment: Have a workbook with several thousand vlookups and formulas and other things and you will quickly realize how nice being able to set calculation to manual can be.